# Reposting comments accidentally moved to chat that don’t belong there

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

Let’s say you see a good question with good answers, but notice something that has not been covered by anybody and you think should be relevant. For example, maybe you think the OP has an apparent misconception that once clarified should quickly lead readers and OP alike to the answer.

You post the observation as a comment. It’s just a hint; not enough information to be a freestanding answer and you don’t think it contributes enough to justify largely duplicating better answers already provided by others. So far so good.

Eventually, however, a chat develops around the comments and the whole bunch gets moved to chat. I presume this is a bulk move, not something where individual comments are cherry-picked by a moderator.

The comment had nothing to do with the “conversation” that developed around the question. It really seems to have been dragged along. The comment loses all usefulness while in chat and stops contributing to the Q/A. It’s not even relevant to the back-and-forth that caused the “move to chat”.

**Does it make sense and is it acceptable to repost the comment on the question? Or would that be frowned upon, perhaps viewed as an unacceptable attempt to override a moderator’s judgement?**

I have no interest on engaging in a tug-war with moderators about “*it’s a comment / no, it’s not / it is too...*”. That’s a waste of everybody’s time. But when something like this  happens, as I’ve seen it happen a couple of times, it’s a shame to lose a small useful contribution and I’d like to know if an effort should or can be made to recover it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wouldn't have a problem with that, since your original comment was doing exactly what comments were intended for and there was no reason for it to have been deleted (that's an unfortunate consequence of migrating comments to chat). In fact, if it was a moderator who migrated the comments to chat, you may have some luck raising a custom flag on the question asking for such comments to be restored so you don't have to repost them. But I understand not wanting to get into a tug-of-war with the moderators so I wouldn't mind you simply reposting the comment instead.

What's important is getting that clarification from the asker, and if your comment isn't there and the asker hasn't had a chance to read or respond to it, nothing gets accomplished.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! My question was of course triggered by a recent event, details of which I felt were not relevant here.  It appears that someone already took notice, and restored mine and another relevant comment already.

Comment: My experience is that posting any comment after a moderator has migrated comments to chat is waste of time because any comments posted after will simply be deleted regardless of content. I don't see reposting a useful comment as avoiding a "tug-of-war" with the moderators, just the opposite, as I've seen moderators justify deleting useful comments for just that reason.

Comment: Comments were intended for posting partial answers?

Comment: @Dukeling: Comments were intended for "getting that clarification from the asker", as I said. If it takes something resembling a partial answer to get there, I don't see a problem. Better than posting that partial answer as an answer and getting criticized for posting what "should have been a comment" instead ("This does not provide an answer to the question..."), or having to edit or otherwise take responsibility for an answer to a question you never intended to commit a complete answer to.

Comment: @BoltClock I suspect we're talking about different types of comments, but that's always the problem when trying to generalise and speaking in abstract terms. Or perhaps we just have different experiences about what most often happens when someone posts a hint / partial answer in a comment (in my experience there is rarely a clarification or any other constructive action and it just ends up being noise).

Answer (score 3):

I say this a lot, and perhaps now is the right time to bring it up on meta for real.  It is my strongly-held and incontrovertibly correct opinion that

> The practice of treating comment threads as ephemeral and "not for extended discussion" is wrong, and is actively harmful to the Stack Overflow community and to the quest for high-quality Q&A.

It would make the entire site better, instantly, if we just *stopped deleting and/or migrating comments*, ever, except when they are spam or abuse.  (It would be even better to make UI changes to treat comments as first-class citizens and associated with a particular revision of an answer, but that's a lot more work.)

If you disagree, please state at least one *concrete* benefit that you believe derives directly from treating comments as ephemeral and/or from discouraging extended discussion in comments, so I can explain why you're wrong.

Comment: The only components which are first-class citizens are those which can be searched.  Comments won't *ever* be searchable on the site since comments are almost *double* that of questions.  And worse, that's not even counting the ones which *were* deleted!

Comment: @Makoto That is indeed one of the ways in which comments currently aren't first-class (although I will observe that chat rooms are even less discoverable; at least comments show up in user activity screens), but there is no valid reason why comments could not be made searchable, and this is therefore no excuse for the status quo.

Comment: You run the risk of turning what is supposed to be the premier site for getting solutions to every programming question into a **social media platform**.  Comments aren't answers.  *Answers* are answers.  Search should hard-prioritize what the site's actual *goal* is.

Comment: @Makoto The site is _already_ a social media platform.  It is impossible for it to be otherwise.  Humans are social animals; every human organization's true primary function is socializing.  As such, any design intended to prevent people from socializing is futile and probably counterproductive. For instance, nothing that this site has ever done in the name of preventing people from socializing in the comments has actually stopped people from socializing in the comments, but they have all produced substantial collateral damage (e.g. the unsearchability of comments).

Comment: \*sigh\*  And this is why we can't have nice things on Stack.  People want to treat this place as a social network when it just ain't that.

Comment: @Makoto  It's not that I "want" to treat it as a social network; it is that it _can't not be_ a social network. For Stack not to be a social network it would have to admit _no interaction whatsoever_ between users.

Comment: While I agree that Stack Overflow is, effectively, a social network (user cards being attached to every non-wiki post, non-wiki *being the default*, comments having just enough functionality to be at least a second-class citizen, etc), calling it a social network because it contains non-zero amounts of social interaction is a bit of a stretch. By that logic, Wikipedia would also be a social network just because talk pages and user disciplinary measures exist, even though they happen almost entirely behind the scenes - imagine meta being our only means of communicating with one another.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, when a post has 50 comments, it might as well have 0. Occasionally / rarely you have comments that stand completely on their own (without needing other comments, that is), but even in those cases they're scattered between a bunch of non-useful comments. Useful conversational comments don't make sense without context. There are usually just too many comments to read all of them to get something useful out of them. When I find myself looking for something on a forum archive I'm usually like "I don't want your life story, just an answer" - [so] shouldn't turn into that.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is: how comments are used is already a problem, let's not make it even worse.

Comment: Although I do agree that trying to stop people from conversing is perhaps a mistake, but there are better solutions, like making chat a more integral part of the site (e.g. built-in chat links on each post), or separating comments into categories.

Answer (score -8):

If you think you may know what the misconception is, and you think you have a suggestion that may solve the problem, **this is an answer**.

Post it in the answer section.

If it is wrong, or inapplicable, the peer review system will make this clear quite quickly and then you can delete it. That is how the website is supposed to work. It is a Q&A. It is not a chat. It is not a discussion board for "hints".

That you think something of value has been lost from the comments section when its only outcome was to spawn a chat/discussion and subsequently got drowned out, is proof positive that *it shouldn't have been in the comments section*.

Comment: Isn't this just the same then if a user posts a question without code, or otherwise they're not clear what they're asking, I could just guess what their problem is, and if I'm wrong the Q&A system of me being downvoted would sort that out?

Comment: @Tas Yes but we generally try _not_ to guess - if the question is too unclear we ask for clarification first. But don't be afraid of downvotes. Occasionally you'll post something that turns out not to be correct - that's fine! That's the system working, and you learning. Trying to hide from that by burying "hints" in the comments section where they can't be reviewed at all is, despite obviously not malicious, not cool. Though I realise that (for reasons passing understanding) I seem to be the only person to think that any more!

Comment: Good news is most of the other SE sites are cracking down on this so perhaps SO will get it right in time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's really easy to say "_don't be afraid of downvotes_" when you have 285k rep and will probably never have any need to gain more, and will probably never lose enough for it to actually effect you or your account

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The site bans you from answering or asking questions- I don't see why regular users wouldn't be scared of downvotes.

Comment: @chevybow It takes a long time for an established user to get an answer ban in this manner, and if you are consistently posting answers that are downvoted to that degree, then you need to be revisiting the quality/accuracy of your answers! A ban for failing to do that is not unwarranted...

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes, it is, but that doesn't mean you should be afraid of downvotes. If anything it means that if your account is not in strong standing then you can simply opt not to take any risks. It does not mean that you should _bypass the peer review system_. That is _double ungood_. Honestly, this should be obvious. If you are unsure of your answer, then isn't peer review what you want/need to happen? Posting your answer in a place where it can't be downvoted is _more dangerous_ then, no?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton:  Honestly I'd say that at about 1,800 reputation you don't need to worry *as* much about reputation, since the spacing between privileges becomes more pronounced and you run less risk of losing major privileges.  Also...this serves as a double reinforcement; if you're *not* sure your answer is correct, you shouldn't answer.  If you *are* sure, then feel confident in answering.  Don't circumvent this process because it's convenient.

Comment: @Makoto I agree with you, and I'm personally not so worried about reputation, however, if I'm not sure if my answer is a full and great answer, why should I not post a comment about my idea and see if that provides additional information someone else might use to write a full answer?

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is not a chatroom! Chat rooms do exist where you can start a discussion with other likeminded individuals if you like, including discussions on questions.

Comment: Two reasons @GrumpyCrouton:  if you *are* right, and it's a comment, **you get no reputation.**  If you are *wrong*, you at least have something you can defend or edit into shape, whereas with comments, you get five minutes before you have to nuke and pave.

Comment: @Makoto I disagree with you there. If I am right, and it's a comment, you are correct I don't get any reputation. However, if I am _wrong_, I not only _lose_ reputation, but I might not have any way to make the post better even after losing some reputation. So in one way, I don't lose any reputation for my possibly correct comment, or I _do_ lose reputation for possibly _incorrect answer_. In my mind, if I don't have a full answer to the question, I shouldn't post an answer to the question.

Comment: So the obvious solution there, @GrumpyCrouton, is to **not post incorrect information.**  If you're answering a question, you're regarded as a subject matter expert.  If you're unwilling to accept that role when answering, then it's just best not to answer.  The only way this site works at all is if we get experts to answer questions and to weigh in with their expertise.  We don't want guesses.

Comment: @Makoto That's exactly my defence, I don't want to post an answer, but I don't see any harm in posting an ephemeral comment that might help _someone_ come up with a proper answer

Comment: ...if you don't want to post an answer, **don't post an answer** @GrumpyCrouton.  This includes half-hearted answers.  This isn't that complex a concept.

Comment: @Makoto I'm talking about posting a _comment_

Comment: "its only outcome was to spawn a chat/discussion" But it wasn't. As the asker said, the discussion was completely orthogonal and irrelevant to their comment; its presence had no bearing on whether it would have unfolded. Their comment was dragged along with the discussion to chat when under normal circumstances it wouldn't have been deleted for any reason until after clarification was provided. *Had* the discussion been provoked by that original comment (whether or not the author intended it), then it'd be best they refrained from posting it again lest it spawn another back-and-forth.