# If someone offers a bounty on another question, would they get notified of comments on the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, bounty

Or the bounty offerer has to manually visit to see if comments are posted?

Comment: Since bounties are about answers, why would *comments* be given a consideration?

Comment: Aren't all questions about answers?!

Comment: Yes, which is why you'd wonder about *comments* when the point of bounties is to expose the question to manifest a desirable *answer*.

Comment: My point was: for the same reason all questions might have comments this bounty offer might have the question commented on, hence he should know, so he can respond back and clarify something a potential answerer is asking for

Comment: Bounties are not about answers, they're about attention. That's *explicitly* stated in the FAQ. Useful comments are a legitimate thing to get out of a bounty...

Comment: Would that not imply that there's a deficiency in the *question* to begin with if a commentator has to comment on it @Honey?  (This would make the bounty process then a bit dubious to begin with, since you don't want to place bounties on bad questions.)

Comment: It may or may not imply that. @Makoto

Comment: @JeremyBanks:  They're about attention insofar as motivating an *answer*.  In this context, attention doesn't include comments.

Comment: Sometimes good advice is given in the comments as well i'd say. Quite often someone will post a comment on a question saying "I suggest trying X and Y", either because it isn't a definitive answer but a suggestion, or maybe the author of the comment doesn't have to time to write out a full fletched answer. So I think comments *should* be considerated as a useful resource information to the bounty offerer.

Comment: @remy_rm Unfortunately, some people say comments regarding suggestions or comments due to the author not having enough time to write a full answer don't belong on questions. (Such as [this comment thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378907/reposting-comments-accidentally-moved-to-chat-that-don-t-belong-there/378945#comment662645_378945))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, bounty owners are not by default notified of new comments on questions they've put bounties on, unless they've followed the question.

However, it's possible to @-reply to a bounty owner, even if they have not commented on the post. This applies even after the bounty has expired.

From the Meta Stack Exchange FAQ [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work):

> #### Who can be notified with this feature?
>
> […]
>
> - For questions: any user who set a bounty on the question (current or expired)

Additionally, bounty owners are notified of new *answers* to the question (but they can't be @-replied to on comments on answers unless they themselves commented as well).

Answer (score 2):

No, bounties won't include the offerer in notifications about activities on the question.

Only the OPs of posts are notified about comments or edit actions. Existing commenters being @-mentioned in comment replies also get notified.

Comment: Not a complete solution but partial workaround is that one who offered bounty should post a comment on question. Then, others can ping him by @name.

Comment: @AmitJoshi Bounty owners can be @-replied to even if they don't leave a comment.